# Multilayer feedforward net fails to train in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, tensorflow, feed-forward

I started with the TensorFlow tutorial to classify the images in the mnist data set using a single layer feedforward neural net. That works OK, i get 80+ percent on the test set. Then I tried to modify it to a multilayer network by adding a new layer in between. After this modification all my attempts to train the network fails. The first couple of iterations the network becomes a bit better but then it stagnates at 11.35% accuracy.

First twenty iterations using 1 hidden layer:

```
Train set: 0.124, test set: 0.098
Train set: 0.102, test set: 0.098
Train set: 0.112, test set: 0.101
Train set: 0.104, test set: 0.101
Train set: 0.092, test set: 0.101
Train set: 0.128, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.12, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.114, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.108, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.1, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.114, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.11, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.122, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.102, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.12, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.106, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.102, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.116, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.11, test set: 0.1135
Train set: 0.124, test set: 0.1135
```

It does not matter how long time I train it, it is stuck here. I have tried to change from rectified linear units to softmax, both yields the same result. I have tried to change the fitness function to e=(y_true-y)^2. Same result.

First twenty iterations using no hidden layers:

```
Train set: 0.124, test set: 0.098
Train set: 0.374, test set: 0.3841
Train set: 0.532, test set: 0.5148
Train set: 0.7, test set: 0.6469
Train set: 0.746, test set: 0.7732
Train set: 0.786, test set: 0.8
Train set: 0.788, test set: 0.7887
Train set: 0.752, test set: 0.7882
Train set: 0.84, test set: 0.8138
Train set: 0.85, test set: 0.8347
Train set: 0.806, test set: 0.8084
Train set: 0.818, test set: 0.7917
Train set: 0.85, test set: 0.8063
Train set: 0.792, test set: 0.8268
Train set: 0.812, test set: 0.8259
Train set: 0.774, test set: 0.8053
Train set: 0.788, test set: 0.8522
Train set: 0.812, test set: 0.8131
Train set: 0.814, test set: 0.8638
Train set: 0.778, test set: 0.8604
```

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
batch_size = 500

# Create the network structure
# ----------------------------

# First layer
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W_1) + b_1)

# Second layer
W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,10]))
b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y_1,W_2) + b_2)

# Loss function
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_true * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

# Training method
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# Train network
# -------------
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
batch, batch_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
for i in range(20):
    print("Train set: " + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch, y_true: batch_labels}))
            + ", test set: " + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_true: mnist.test.labels}))) 
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch, y_true: batch_labels})
    batch, batch_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

So with this code it does not work, but if I change from

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y_1,W_2) + b_2)
```

to

```
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W_1) + b_1)
```

then it works. What have I missed?

Edit: Now I have it working. Two changes was needed,first of all initiating the weights to random values instead of zero (yes, actually it was the weights that needed to be not zero, the bias as zero was OK despite the relu function). The second thing is strange to me: If I remove the softmax function from the output layer and instead of manually applying the formula for cross entropy uses the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y,y_true) function then it works. As I understand it that should be the same.. And previously I also tried with the sum of squared errors which didn't work either.. Anyway, the following code is working. (Quite ugly though, but working..) With 10k iterations it gets me 93.59% accuracy on the test set, so not optimal in any way but better than the one with no hidden layer. After only 20 iterations it's already up to 65%.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
batch_size = 500

# Create the network structure
# ----------------------------

# First layer
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784,10], stddev=0.1))
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10], stddev=0.1))
y_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,W_1) + b_1)

# Second layer
W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10,10], stddev=0.1))
b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10], stddev=0.1))
y = tf.matmul(y_1,W_2) + b_2

# Loss function
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y,y_true))

# Training method
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# Train network
# -------------
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
batch, batch_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
for i in range(10000):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print("Train set: " + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch, y_true: batch_labels}))
                + ", test set: " + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_true: mnist.test.labels}))) 
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch, y_true: batch_labels})
    batch, batch_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

Comment: your intermediate layer is only 10 neurons wide, that might be a bottleneck. What happens if you make it bigger? Using convolutions should improve the accuracy

Comment: also change the training method GradientDescentOptimizer with something else like rmsprop or adam

Comment: I agree that the intermediate layer is too narrow. The optimizer choice may not play a role in classification performance. However, because the training error keeps bouncing back and forth, I would recommend reducing the step size from 0.5 to 0.01 or even lower.

Comment: The strange thing is that it stagnates at exactly the same error-rate if I change number of hidden units, change learning rate or change training method.. If I get 80% accuracy with no hidden units and 10 output neurons, then I should be able to get at least the same with 10 hidden units. In worst case they will map 1:1 with the corresponding inputs and yield exactly the same result? If I train with the complete data set instead of a random batch, then it only improves in the first iteration before it stagnates at the same 11.35% correct. The bouncing is because of training on random subsets.

Answer (score 2):

Few suggestions:

1- Add standard deviation to both weight variable initialization, instead of initializing with `zeros`:

```
weight_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784,10], stddev=0.1))
```

2- Lower the learning rate until the accuracy value show a varying behavior.

3- When using RELU, initialize bias with a slightly positive value. This suggestion probably has less to do with the issue that you are seeing.

```
bias_1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(.05, shape=[10]))
```